# Elasticsearch NEST query for datetime

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to get last 15 minute records from database using Elasticsearch Nest Query

what problem this query has?

```
var response = await _client SearchAsync<dynamic>(s=> s
.Index("someproj")
.From(0)
.Size(size)
.MatchAll()
  .Query(q => q.
  .Bool(b => b.
  .Filter(f => f.
    .DateRange(dr => dr.Field(time).GreaterThanOrEqual($"now-{15}m")
    )
   )
  )
 )
.Scroll(scrollTime)
    .Source(src=> src.IncludeAll())

);
```

Comment: Could you share your index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Include TimeZone in your query:

```
query = query && new QueryContainerDescriptor<IndexActors>()
.Bool(b => b.Filter(f => f.DateRange(dt => dt
        .Field(field => field.BirthDate)
        .GreaterThanOrEquals(birthdate)
        .LessThanOrEquals(birthdate)
        .TimeZone("+00:00"))));
```